# Correct syntax file for index.php in slim

Tags: php, slim

A sample file for index.php in slim micro-framework which comes in public folder ?
I use the slim/slim-skeleton using composer and index.php file for that is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the answer.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new \Slim\Container;
$container['db'] = getConnection();
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->write("Welcome to Slim!");
    return $response;
});
function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="xxx";
    $dbpass="xxxxxxxx";
    $dbname="xxxxxx";
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   // var_dump($dbh);
    return $dbh;
    }

$app->run();

?>
```